# Using google drive to upload files

Tags: r, google-drive-api

I am using the googledrive package of R to access a shared folder within my Google Drive. However, when I type drive_find() an the name of my folder, an error of permissions appears:

```
drive_find(pattern='Github-Colombia Project', type='folder') %>%
```

an the error goes:

```
+   drive_reveal("permissions")
Error: Client error: (403) Forbidden
Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient
authentication scopes.
• domain: global
• reason: insufficientPermissions
• message: Insufficient Permission: Request had
  insufficient authentication scopes.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

these is the current status of the folder:

[image]

Can you please help me out on this?

Comment: What scopes are you using for the request? Moreover, what permissions do you have for this shared drive? While you may be able to view the files in the Drive UI, you might not be able to retrieve them using the API.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I managed to do that by changing the scopes:

```
drive_auth(
  email = gargle::gargle_oauth_email(),
  path = NULL,
  scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
  cache = gargle::gargle_oauth_cache(),
  use_oob = gargle::gargle_oob_default(),
  token = NULL
)
```

which asks for a novel authentication.